# php foearch with array

Tags: php, foreach

what do i need to change for my codes?
the echo is just 1 letter `m`

this is my code :

```
$string = 'mars@email.com,123,12,1|art@hur.com,321,32,2';

$output = array();

foreach (explode('|', $string) as $key => $person) {
    $output[] = array(
        'email'   =>    $person[0],
        'score'   =>    $person[1],
        'street'  =>    $person[2],
        'rank'    =>    $person[3]
    );
    echo $output[0]['email']; 
}
```

OUTPUT : `m`

the output should be:

```
$email1  = mars@email.com
$score1  = 123
$street1 = 12
$rank1   = 1

$email2  = art@hur.com
$score2  = 321
$street2 = 21
$rank2   = 2
```

is it possible to do this code to output the email1 and email2?
is my code correct or do i need to change something?

thank you.

Comment: Adding to Phil's neat solution, I'd advise you not to use strings this way. Where's the string coming from?

Comment: Copy-pasted your code. The output is 'mm' not 'm'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a nested loop; the first to iterate over the pipe delimited data and the second for the comma delimited entries.

```
$string = 'mars@email.com,123,12,1|art@hur.com,321,32,2';

$entries = explode('|', $string);
foreach ($entries as $i => $entry) {
    $parts = explode(',', $entry, 4);
    if (count($parts) < 4) {
        // not enough parts, throw an error or something
    }
    printf('$email%d  = %s%s', $i+1, $parts[0], PHP_EOL);
    printf('$score%d  = %s%s', $i+1, $parts[1], PHP_EOL);
    printf('$street%d = %s%s', $i+1, $parts[2], PHP_EOL);
    printf('$rank%d   = %s%s', $i+1, $parts[3], PHP_EOL);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Example here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/82HbtT